# Calling void functions inside a condition - asserting inside an if

Tags: c++, visual-c++, macros, assert

Is there any secret trick that I've overlooked, maybe in C++11/14, that would allow me to call `DebugBreak()` (a void function) while in the top scope of the if-statement?

If `DebugBreak()` would return anything, I guess it would've been "trivial".

**Background**

In my pursuit of writing a specialized Assert-function, I'm stuck. Currently, code looks like this:

```
if ( MyClass* instance = GetLastObject() )
```

I want to add a CHK() macro that developers can drop in:

```
if ( MyClass* instance = CHK( GetLastObject() ) )
```

If the condition within `CHK()` is false, an assert will be displayed. With some *Lambda magic* I'm able to call `DebugBreak()` inside the `CHK` macro and it works fine, except that the execution is halted inside the *Lambda*; forcing developers to move one step down the callstack if hit.

If I could force the compiler to inline the lambda, that could work as well, but I haven't found any way of doing that either.

*Edit:* A simplified version of the `CHK(f)` macro, sorry for formatting:

```
[&]() {auto CHK_test = (f); if (CHK_test) return CHK_test; else { __debugbreak(); return (decltype(CHK_test))0; } } ( )
```

Comment: You want the debugged to halt execution inside `GetLastObject()`?

Comment: @RickAstley the calling function, I think

Comment: @RickAstley No, I want it to halt in the if-statement. In this case, if `GetLastObject()` returned nullptr

Comment: If `DebugBreak()` is called in the macro `CHK()` you could use a sequence operator. However, according to your code sample the return value of `GetLastObject()` should be the last expression of the macro `CHK()`. IMHO it would make things easier if you would provide a the code (or a "sketch") of your macro `CHK()` also.

Comment: If inlining is sufficient, surely you could just use an inlined templated function instead of "lambda magic"?

Comment: What about `else` ?

Comment: @Galik I specifically wanted to make a "drop-in" macro that wouldn't bloat the code as much as `else { assert(false) }`